# Problems with displaying multiple children of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new with React and I'm training in doing a simple portfolio-ish app. And I've run into some troubles with my sidebar.

What I want to achieve : changing the icon before the "navigation text" if this page is active or not AND diplaying the said text.

Right now, I've succeed doing one but not both, either i've got the icon or the text, but I can't succeed in having both. To be more specific, when I add the {text} in my NavLink, it made the icon disapear and I would like the show both.

Thank you in advance for your help !

My code (tell me if you need more) :

Navbar.jsx

```
import { CustomNavLink } from "./CustomNavLink";
import "./Navbar.css";
import { useId } from "react";

export function Navbar () {
    const navCategories = [
        {
            id: useId(),
            to: "/",
            text: "About me",
        },
        {
            id: useId(),
            to: "/skills",
            text: "Skills",
        },
        {
            id: useId(),
            to: "/work",
            text: "Projects",
        },
        {
            id: useId(),
            to: "/contact",
            text: "Contact",
        },
    ]

    return <>
        <header className="col-3">
            <div className="title">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <h2 className="fs-5">Subtitle</h2>
            </div>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <ul>
                    {
                        navCategories.map(navCategory => (
                            <li id={navCategory.id} key={navCategory.id}>
                                <CustomNavLink to={navCategory.to} inActiveIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>} activeIcon={<i className="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>} text={navCategory.text} />
                            </li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </>
}
```

CustomNavLink.jsx

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export function CustomNavLink ({ to, activeIcon, inActiveIcon, text }) {
    return (
    <NavLink to={to}>
        {({ isActive }) => isActive ? activeIcon && text : inActiveIcon && text}
    </NavLink>
    );
};
```

Comment: you have not included the text or isActive value in CustomNavLinks? {({ isActive }) => isActive ? activeIcon : inActiveIcon} {text}

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I've already tried that, but when I do it, the text is visible but not the icon.

I'll edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: `&&` is not an element concatenation.  `activeIcon && text` should be `( <> {activeIcon} {text} </> )`

Comment: Yeah ! It's working ! Thank you very much ! Do you know where I can find such info on concatenaton in react ?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd make an answer of prosperity (don't need to accept it)

```
<NavLink to={to}>
        {({ isActive }) => isActive ? activeIcon && text : inActiveIcon && text}
</NavLink>
```

this is tenary, here active is evaluated and the test true or false is returned
{ active ? 'true' : 'false'  }

the bug you have was using a logicalANDexpression https://es5.github.io/#x11.11 inside your tenary

```
{ activeIcon && text }
```

which was checking if activeIcon is "truthy" and then returning text

in React / JSX you can put these inside the return of the component and conditionally display things, you could write it as simple as this:

```
<NavLink to={to}>
   {isActive ? activeIcon : inActiveIcon}
   {text}
</NavLink>
```

for the purpose of learning though you could use the suggetsion given by @possum

```
<NavLink to={to}>
   {isActive ? <>{activeIcon} {text}<> : <>{inActiveIcon} {text}<>}
   {text}
</NavLink>
```

so in JSX you can return DOM elements directly. the <></> is a placeholder element because the return can on have one element but it could be valid element, a string or even another component

```
<NavLink to={to}>
   {isActive ? <div><ActiveIconComponent /> <span>{text}</span></div> : <>{inActiveIcon} {text}<>}
   {text}
</NavLink>
```

hope that helps someone.